# Pin Items Where & When They Appear on Screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do you pin items to the place where they appear when they are first encountered on the screen?

I have a few elements that have their position set to absolute. After you first encounter the item, I would like them to become fixed to that position when you continue to scroll on the screen.

(ie, item on the bottom left corner of the screen and would like to keep it pinned there when scrolling after the item is encountered)

I've been using ScrollMagic, but when the items are pinned they are shifted to the middle.

**EDIT** Figured something out using jQuery

Comment: What did you try yourself, do you have any sample code.

Comment: @mouser just added!

Answer (score 0):

To make an element move with your screen in a fixed position, you can to the following:

```
yourElement{
    position: fixed;
    top: 300px;
    left: 400px;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have to work with layers, take a look:

```css
.layer1{
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

.layer2{
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="layer1"></div>
<div class="layer2">
Normal content
</div>
```